# Converting Zebra Pagination PHP script to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm using [Zebra Pagination](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-pagination/) to paginate data from MySQL. The example script is already good enough to paginate them, but now I wanted to use prepared statement for it.

The Zebra Pagination script usually goes like this.

```
$records_per_page = 10; 
require 'Zebra_Pagination.php'; 
$pagination = new Zebra_Pagination();
$limit1 = ($pagination->get_page() - 1) * $records_per_page;
$limit2 = $records_per_page;

$MySQL = '
    SELECT
        SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        *
    FROM
        `magz`.`magazine`
    ORDER BY `magz_release` DESC
    LIMIT $limit1, $limit2';    

if (!($result = @mysqli_query($link, $MySQL))) {
    die(mysqli_error($link));       
}   

$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rows')); 
$pagination->records($rows['rows']);
$pagination->records_per_page($records_per_page);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //render queries here
}

$pagination->render();
```

This is my first time using prepared statement and I did some fiddling. But there is something wrong. Either:

1. It will pop out `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean` message when I did `fetch_assoc` for the rows.
2. Or displaying the correct queries but the pagination link isn't rendering when I put a number for the rows.

This is my code. If anyone could point out where did I go wrong, I will appreciate it much.

```
$records_per_page = 2;  
require "js/Zebra_Pagination.php";
$pagination = new Zebra_Pagination();
$limit1 = ($pagination->get_page() - 1) * $records_per_page;
$limit2 = $records_per_page;

$stmt = $link->prepare("
    select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
        c.comic_name, CONCAT(pa.people_name, '/',pb.people_name) as 'author', ct.city_name, p.publisher_name, c.comic_id 
    from ref_author ra 
    natural join ref_publisher rp 
    natural join ref_setting rs
    inner join comic c on c.comic_id = ra.comic_id 
    inner join people pa on pa.people_id = ra.people_writer_id 
    inner join people pb on pb.people_id = ra.people_illust_id 
    inner join publisher p on p.publisher_id = rp.publisher_id
    inner join city ct on ct.city_id = rs.city_id
    where rs.province_id = ?
    LIMIT $limit1, $limit2
");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET["prov"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->bind_result($comic_name, $comic_author, $comic_city, $comic_publish, $comic_id);

//This is where the problem starts
$rows = $result->fetch_assoc($link->execute("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rows")); 
$pagination->records($rows["rows"]);
$pagination->records_per_page($records_per_page);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo 
        "<tr>
            <td><a href='comic.php?comic=".$comic_id."'>".$comic_name."</a></td>
            <td>".$comic_author."</td>
            <td>".$comic_city."</td>
            <td>".$comic_publish."</td>
        </tr>";
}

$pagination->render();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: have you maked sure or do debuging the query of pagination is right?

Comment: @f_anto I've run the SQL query and there's no problem. Running the stock Zebra Pagination code also has no problem. As I've said, the problem might come from the `fetch_assoc` part of the code in the prepared statement.

Comment: @MekaMedina did you find the asnwer for this solution? because im stuck in it right now? thanks

Comment: @PascaleAbouAbdo I've actually solved this myself, it's more of a turnaround solution so it may look dirty. I can't answer my own question so I've pasted my codes here: http://pastebin.com/8Fy0P9aV

Comment: @MekaMedina thank you a lot